# Problem with displaying only certain rows from excel with pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, parsing, xls

I know my code is super untidy and may look horrible but as not even amateur I am trying to create simple code to allow me see planned closure of specific highway. I have managed to extract desirable sheet every day, and column that I want. The only issue I have now is to show only rows that starts with "M5" and "M6" string. I tried .str.startwith("M6"), but always giving me an error. Also tried to implement .str.contains, with the same effect.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://nationalhighways.co.uk/media/s2pjwbuk/7-day-closure-report-26-july-web-upload.xls'
dt = datetime.now()
x = dt.weekday()
column_name = [5]

print(x)

if x == 0:
    sheet_name = "Monday"
    data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name)
    print(data)
if x == 1:
    sheet_name = "Tuesday"
    data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name)
    print(data)
if x == 2:
    sheet_name = "Wednesday"
    data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name)
    print(data)
if x == 3:
    sheet_name = "Thursday"
    data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name)
    print(data)

if x == 4:
    sheet_name = "Friday"
    data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name)
    print(data)
if x > 4:
    sheet_name = "Monday"
    data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name)
    print(data)
```

data = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name, usecols=column_name.str.startwith("M6"))

or

print(data.str.contains"M6")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) inside a function chain:

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd


today = datetime.now().strftime("%A")

url = "https://nationalhighways.co.uk/media/s2pjwbuk/7-day-closure-report-26-july-web-upload.xls"

df = (pd
      .read_excel(io=url, sheet_name=today, skiprows=1, usecols=["Closure details, including diversions"])
      .rename(columns={"Closure details, including diversions": "closures"})
      .query("closures.str.startswith('M5') | closures.str.startswith('M6')")
      .drop_duplicates()
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                                                               closures
0                                  M56 Eastbound link road closure to A34 Northbound due to gas works 
1  M6 Southbound junction 27 to junction 26 - Carriageway Closure for Horticulture (Cutting and Pla...
2  M6 North & Southbound Junction 21A - 26 lane closures and carriageway closures due to improvemen...
3        M6 southbound Jct 13 to jct 12 \ncarriageway closure for carriageway - reconstruction/renewal
4  M62 eastbound and westbound Jct 36 to Western Interchange.\nCarriageway closures for survey work...
5  M62 westbound Jct 29 to Jct 27 and m62 westbound jct 29 entry slip closed \nCarriageway closure ...
6  M621 anticlockwise Jct 7 to Jct 1.\nCarriageway and lane closures including narrow lanes and spe...
7                                                   M65 eastbound J5 to J7 - lane closure for barriers
8      M67 Eastbound and Westbound J1a to J3 - Carriageway Closure for Structure - New/Reconstruction
```

Comment: Thank you! You are great, I would never thought to do it this way

Comment: You are most welcome, please mark the question as solved if it works for you.